# Alternatives to request-promise-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request-promise

I was looking for modern modules that implement basic HTTP methods such as GET, POST in Node.js.

I guess the most popular is [`request`](https://github.com/request/request). The async/await version of it is called [`request-promise-native`](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native).

Recently I learned that these modules are being [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142). So, what modern alternatives can I use that are built on the async/await paradigm?

Comment: Did you follow the link to alternatives in that issue?

Comment: I found only [bent](https://github.com/mikeal/bent)

Comment: There's a whole list linked from that issue thread. But also: why don't you use bent, then?

Comment: It looks like bent has not gained popularity (7000 downloads weekly). I want to choose something I can get help for.

Comment: Then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334548/alternatives-to-request-promise-native/60335051#comment106727440_60334548

Comment: See also https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#comparison

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). It is based on the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API in modern browsers. Not only is it promise-based it also has an [actual standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) behind it.

The only reason you wouldn't use `fetch` is if you don't like the API. Then I'd suggest using something cross-platform like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent).

I personally find using the same API on the server and browser eases maintainability and offers potential for code reuse.

Answer (score 5):

Just for having another option in mind, I would suggest using the node native `http` module.

```js
import * as http from 'http';

async function requestPromise(path: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(path, (resp) => {
            let data = '';

            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            resp.on('end', () => {
                resolve(data);
            });

        }).on("error", (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}

(async function () {
    try {
        const result = await requestPromise('http://www.google.com');
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

On the same github issue for `request` there is another link which talks about the alternatives. You can see them [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143). It clearly explains different types and wht style they are (promise/callback).

Answer (score 1):

[Got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#comparison) is pretty sweet.

*"Got was created because the popular request package is bloated.
Furthermore, Got is fully written in TypeScript and actively
maintained." - https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#faq*

[image]